# dropdwon send always last value in filter

Tags: php, laravel, filtering, laravel-blade

i'm trying to do a filter using Dropdown but it's always sending the last value to the link option
[image]

always sending the last option
[image]

the filter controller work fine. i believe the problem is in the dropdown menu in blade it doesn't send the option the link

this is my blade

```xml
<form action="{{ action('App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController@processForm') }}" method="POST" class="woocommerce-ordering product-filter">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" value="alpha" name="sortoption"id="alpha"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="desc" name="sortoption" id="desc">
    <input type="hidden" value="asc" name="sortoption" id="asc">
                                
    <span class="orderby-label hide-desktop">Sort by</span>
    <span te class="perpage-label">Sort by</span>
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby filterSelect" aria-label="Shop order" data-class="select-filter-orderby">
        <option for="alpha">Ordre Alphabetique</option>
        <option for="desc">Prix Decroissant</option>
        <option for="asc">Prix Croissant</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for `<option>` is wrong. `for` is an attribute used in `<label>` tags. The attribute to set an option's value is `value`.

You do not need the hidden inputs either.

```xml
<form action="{{ action('App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController@processForm') }}" method="POST" class="woocommerce-ordering product-filter">
    @csrf
    <span class="orderby-label hide-desktop">Sort by</span>
    <span class="perpage-label">Sort by</span>
    <select name="sortoption" class="orderby filterSelect" aria-label="Shop order" data-class="select-filter-orderby">
        <option value="alpha">Ordre Alphabetique</option>
        <option value="desc">Prix Decroissant</option>
        <option value="asc">Prix Croissant</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: little details we miss thanks a lot